# Swift Error: 'Sequence' requires the types 'T' and 'ArraySlice<T>' be equivalent

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to update a math library to be compatible with Swift 3, but I'm running into an error:

`'Sequence' requires the types 'T' and 'ArraySlice<T>' be equivalent`

Apple's documentation on Sequence recommends that makeIterator() method returns an iterator, which it does. And it seems that the iterator is returning an element in the `grid` variable, which is of variable `T`. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here. Any advice would be helpful.

```
public struct Matrix<T> where T: FloatingPoint, T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    public typealias Element = T

    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    var grid: [Element]

    public init(rows: Int, columns: Int, repeatedValue: Element) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        self.grid = [Element](repeating: repeatedValue, count: rows * columns)
    }
... 
}

extension Matrix: Sequence { // <-- getting error here
    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<ArraySlice<Element>> {
        let endIndex = rows * columns
        var nextRowStartIndex = 0

        return AnyIterator {
            if nextRowStartIndex == endIndex {
                return nil
            }

            let currentRowStartIndex = nextRowStartIndex
            nextRowStartIndex += self.columns

            return self.grid[currentRowStartIndex..<nextRowStartIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code compiles fine as Swift 3.1 (Xcode 8.3.3). The error

```
'Sequence' requires the types 'T' and 'ArraySlice<T>' be equivalent
```

occurs when compiling as Swift 4 (Xcode 9, currently beta), because then
the `Sequence` protocol already defines the

```
associatedtype Element where Self.Element == Self.Iterator.Element
```

which conflicts with your definition. You can either choose a different
name for your type alias, or just remove it (and use `T` instead):

```
public struct Matrix<T> where T: FloatingPoint, T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {

    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    var grid: [T]

    public init(rows: Int, columns: Int, repeatedValue: T) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        self.grid = [T](repeating: repeatedValue, count: rows * columns)
    }
}

extension Matrix: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<ArraySlice<T>> {
        let endIndex = rows * columns
        var nextRowStartIndex = 0

        return AnyIterator {
            if nextRowStartIndex == endIndex {
                return nil
            }

            let currentRowStartIndex = nextRowStartIndex
            nextRowStartIndex += self.columns

            return self.grid[currentRowStartIndex..<nextRowStartIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs with both Swift 3 and 4.